# Get key name in an existing provider

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I want to find out what key name provided from an external provider my database is using in an encrypted database.

This is an example taken from Microsoft website.

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY EKM_askey1   
FROM PROVIDER EKM_Provider1  
WITH   
    ALGORITHM = RSA_2048,   
    CREATION_DISPOSITION = CREATE_NEW  
    , PROVIDER_KEY_NAME  = 'key10_user1' ;  
GO
```

But I don't know how to learn whether this is `CREATE_NEW` or `OPEN_EXISTING` and have no clue what view contains information about this `key10_user1` as mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.cryptographic_providers;
```

to get the `provider id` and then query using [sys.dm_cryptographic_provider_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-cryptographic-provider-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_cryptographic_provider_keys(1234567);  
GO
```